# Light fixture has 3 white wires together, 2 black together, and one by itself, how do I connect a new fixture?

Tags: light-fixture, light

The light fixture I removed has 3 white wires basically melted together.  One black wire by itself, and the other two blacks are connected.  How would I go about wiring a new fixture with one white and one black? [image]

Comment: Those white wires "basically melted together" were soldered. I hope there was a wire nut covering them for electrical insulation. Wiring isn't soldered very often, at least not any more.

Comment: Q: "How would I go about wiring a new fixture with one white and one black?" - A: The exact same way the old one was wired. There's no need to get creative - assuming the old one worked before ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you have a photo from before the old fixture was removed fully?
You need a hot plus a neutral for a light.

Likely the bare black wire is your hot switch lead, something you can verify with a non-contact circuit tracer (a tool you should own for safety sake, for example Klein NCVT-1).  The white neutrals often get all tied together, don't worry about overthinking that one too much, just hook your white there.

The connected hots might be some totally other circuit using this box as a waypoint.  Unless there are more lights run by the same switch, or something else, it's best to just ignore them and move on.

Comment: Scott, you were correct about the set up.  I didn’t have a non-contact circuit tracer. But my neighbor did and checked for me.  I honestly didn’t know what that was and I’ll be getting one tomorrow.  Thank you for your help.

Comment: @EnriqueRosario the normal way of saying "thank you" is to click the up arrow for the answer. If this completely solved your problem, you can even click the check mark so others know it's been solved.

Comment: Aside from properly connecting wires, it looks like you have problems with the condition of some of that wiring. As FreeMan mentioned that white pigtail needs to be totally covered with a wirenut which may mean trimming off some of the copper before hand. Also, I see some bare copper in your pic in the center of the box (white? black?). If some of that old wiring has cracked insulation exposing bare wire you need to make sure it's repaired/insulated or replaced before you close up that box. If you're unsure how to handle it you might want to call an electrician.